# How do I fix 1px margin on Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Here an example http://jsbin.com/oqisuv/

CSS

```
body {
    background:#e7ebf2 url(http://i.imgur.com/R2VB6.png) center repeat-y;
}
.menu {
    width:989px;
    margin:auto;
    height:100px;
    background:#666666;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
 <div class="menu">Hello</div>
</body>
```

If you view an example above on Google Chrome you will see the `.menu` looks like have a `margin-left:-1px` or `margin-right:1px`.

On Firefox & IE it's look great. How do I fix this one?

Comment: here's a picture, above is firefox, below is chrome. i dont see any difference http://i.imgur.com/OSu9D.png

Comment: @AndreiS here is my Chrome.. http://i.imgur.com/W1Mhj.png may I know what OS and Chrome version you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 

html {
    margin-left: 1px;
}

}
```

[Background center with chrome (bug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454019/background-center-with-chrome-bug)

```
body {   
 background:#e7ebf2 url(http://i.imgur.com/R2VB6.png) 50% 0 repeat-y;   
} 

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    body {
        background-position: 50.001% 0;
    }
}
```

http://philfreo.com/blog/fixing-safaris-1px-background-image-centering-problem/

Comment: First snippet creates a space between full-size background and full-size elements. Second snippet only works for window widths larger than ~1660px. I really need to align a large semi-transparent background image of element A with a smaller element B, which has a semi-transparent background colour. If the two were 100% opaque, I would just increase slightly the width of the smaller one, so that it would cover any "misplaced" pixels. Plz plz plz =)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to rudsy's answer, but this one seems to work better:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    body {
        background-position: 49.999% 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome & firefox rendered differently it's better if you want result same in all browser the always give width in **EVEN** values not in **ODD**. So, write like this:

```
.menu {
    width:990px;
}
```

Check this http://jsbin.com/oqisuv/2

**UPDATED**
If you want it's work perfect in chrome the you can use this:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .menu {
    width:990px;
 }
```

Check this http://jsbin.com/oqisuv/5/

Comment: It will fixed on webkit and not for IE or Firefox

Comment: On FF or IE you will see have `margin-left:-1px`. Shadow is gone on left.

Answer (score 0):

Set the body margin to 0 ...Try this css:

```
body {
background:#e7ebf2 url(http://i.imgur.com/R2VB6.png) center repeat-y;
margin: 0;
}
.menu {
width:990px;
height:100px;
margin: 0 auto;
background:#666666;
line-height:100px;
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most cross-browser and *future-proof* solution is to attach background to centered block itself (or to its centered parent that has horizontal padding for background to be visible on the outside of its child).

Attempts to achieve pixel-perfect matching of background and block centered independently (especially with hacks for specific browsers) is dead-end road.