# Background-size:cover, 1px whitespace to the left

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem on my site about background-size:cover
I have been testing it in Firefox all along, but when i load the page in Google Chrome, i get 1px white all to the left. When i use background-position:-1px the white edge left goes away (but then i get it to the right). Is there any way to fix this, and still keep the cover?

I applied this to my body: background:url("images/baggrund.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover

I can not link to the site at the moment, but hope i described it clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Edit: added a screenshot, top comes from firefox, bottom from Chrome.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What element is your CSS `background-size` set to?

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: I am sadly not allowed to give any links, or link my code, but i used:
background:url("images/baggrund.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
background-size: cover;

Comment: But you are allowed to post a screenshot?

Comment: i only cutted out a small part, i assume that will be fine ^^

Comment: it seems all solution are not work. what is your final solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That did not work for me, because i used background cover, but i just added a chrome specific line to set my background-size to 101%, that seems to fix it (for the eye). 
Thanks for the input.

Comment: It's make background not cover. When you resize your browser background too.

Comment: This worked for me `background-size: 100.1% auto;` for fixed width

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
background: background:url("images/baggrund.jpg") no-repeat 49% center fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

In chrome, when you use "background-size: cover", if the xpos of background-image is no less than 50%, you will meet that problem.

So, the xpos is set to 49% (or 49.9% to reduce the error) instead of "center" will fix that problem.

My English is not good, i hope you know what i mean.

Comment: nice fix , just ran in to this with bg set at center top. funny bug

Comment: Still seems to be a things. Come on chrome :(

Answer (score 3):

101% might work fine but you could also try this fine-grained solution:

```css
background-size: calc(100% + 1px);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative :**

Another solution would be to reduce or increase the background image's width by 1px in an image editing program if it wouldn't matter.

Otherwise, this should do it (as @estrar pointed out) : [How do I fix 1px margin on Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752201/how-do-i-fix-1px-margin-on-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Changed `background-size: cover;` to `background-size: 100%;`. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the background property to the body tag, which would cause it to cover the whole page.

You could also try applying the following style to the body and html tags:

```
html,body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: It is at the moment apply'd to the body tag. It also works fine, just not in Google Chrome.

Comment: @user1765065 Try setting the margins and padding to 0 on the html and body tags

Comment: I have set both to 0 in my *

Comment: Could it be this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752201/how-do-i-fix-1px-margin-on-google-chrome

Answer (score 0):

So I tried all of the solutions out there and could not get that last px to work. Tried all sorts of big and small image dimensions too.

My problem was that I was using **svg**. I bit the bullet and switched to **png**.

```
  /* background: url("/static/images/orgchart-background.svg") no-repeat; */
  background: url("/static/images/orgchart-background.png") no-repeat; 
  background-size: 100% 100%;
```