# 1px margin difference FF & Opera vs Chrome (Mac)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, opera, margin

I have this annoying problem with Chrome (or FF?). I haven't checked on IE yet.
There is one pixel difference in rendering and I have no idea where I can dig for more. I've used all inspectors for the three browsers (FF, Opera, Chrome) to see, if there is anything to tweak, with no success. It is either a bug, or I am blind for this error.

See an example here: www.vanwright.com/catalogue/le-kex-walking-kids/

The problem refers to the left margin of the first images from the left in both rows. Chrome shows 2px border, while other browsers show 1px, which is what I am after. 
Is it caused by nth-of-type selector? 
Probably not, because here: www.vanwright.com/collections/ it seems to have the same problem (margin-left: -10px shows with a 1px line in Chrome, while there is no space in FF/Opera).

I am lost. Any ideas?

Thanks,
pop

Comment: you have a number of CSS errors on the containers containing the images before you ever even begin considering div.column.pi-pad width and margin

Comment: specifically, 3 items across needs a minimum of 966px of space, but you've only got 960 defined in div.span-12 and div.maincontent.column

Comment: actually I Was wrong, you need 976px BEFORE margin considerations

Comment: and lastly, the reason everything is off is because what you are actually seeing is the background on that page, which is either sized incorrectly, or has additional margins built in (in which case it is positioned incorrectly).

Comment: I actually try to use 980px of width out of 960px defined with a grid. I know this is probably not a very graceful solution, but because of this "space deficit" I am basically doing all this nth-of-type selector madness. Every image on that page should have a 1px border around it. Yes, the white background is a part of an image, and I've just checked again - the white part is 980px wide. So this is not the graphics.

Comment: ... the background image is also centered, so it is not the position.

The math goes like this:
1px + 322px + 1px + 327px + 1px + 327px + 1px = 980px

And somewhere in positioning lies the truth. Where?

Comment: See my answer below, as to why your math above doesn't work, you're equation is wrong ;)

You've got a 960px div centered, meaning there's an additional 10px to either side, and you need to get over to the left side to start.

You did margin-left: -9px for the leftmost container, you needed -10px;

Then you have overflow problems, hide your overflow on all the containers.

Comment: then you see that your equation looks more like this:

-(-10px) + 322px + 1px + 327px + 1px + 318px + 1px = 970px.  You can't expand more on the left because you can't get out of the 960px box that you've already margined out of on the left side. If you don'tuse overflow:hidden, it "looks" like you get out, but now some of your margins will mess up as overflow from other columns invades that space. Only true solution is to do what I did below and fix the width of the bounding boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Chrome bug. Thanks to runspired for taking time. Sorry for anyone trying to fix the unfixable.

[Background center with chrome (bug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454019/background-center-with-chrome-bug)

Comment: incidentally, Chrome's suck is yet another reason I'm not looking forward to Blink. I seriously spend 4x longer fixing things for Chrome than for any other browser, even IE6. (because between the IE6 shunt, and knowing exactly the couple bugs that IE has, it's easy to fix)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

To fix and maintain `960px` layout:

remove all the `:nth-of-type` css on `.pi-pad`

change the css for .pi-pad to read: `.pi-pad {margin: 1px 1px 1px 0; width: 318px; padding: 0px;}`

Fix background to math 960px layout ( I think it is currently designed for a 979px layout);

**Option 2**

Expand current layout to match background. (which is clunky, because the background's width is no divisible by 3)

CSS for `.container` and `.span-12` should specify `width: 979px`

Change either the `.pi-pad:nth-of-type(3n+1)` or `.pi-pad:nth-of-type(3n)` CSS to read `width: 325px;` and remove the other.

Change the `.pi-pad` CSS to read `.pi-pad {margin: 1px 1px 1px 0; width: 324px; padding: 0px;}`

**=========EDIT=========**

I posted this before I saw your replies above, and I also forgot to hide your overflow.

Using option 2, and now that I know for sure it is 980px (it looked like 979 when I measured)

`.container` and `.span-12` should have `width: 980px;`

Change the `.pi-pad` CSS to read `.pi-pad {overflow: hidden; margin: 1px 1px 1px 0; width: 325px; padding: 0px;}`

Use `.pi-pad:nth-of-type(3n)` OR `.pi-pad:nth-of-type(3n+1)` should specify `width: 326px;` and delete the other.

Comment: Nope! I have rebuilt the template, changed css and no, it doesn't help. The problem seems to lie within the parent div (which is now #span-pi and is 980px wide).See the screenshot (magnified) and 1 pixel shift to the right http://vanwright.com/_temp/Screen-shot-2013-04-04-at-20.53.jpg

Comment: Now I'm almost sure it's a bug, 'cause Safari AND Chrome for iOS render this particular thing correct. My desktop version is 26.0.1410.43 (for Mac). ;(

Comment: It is definitely a background-image problem with Chrome. Try resizing the window's width and see how that one pixel (left or right) is behaving. O_o Now what?

Comment: On firefox, chrome, and safari the changes I made rendered correctly.

Comment: but then again, I'm on a 27" iMac, so for all I know that Chrome bug doesn't show up for me.

Comment: I am also on 27" Mac, and resizing Chrome's window revealed the bug. I have now altered the layout so that this annoying thing doesn't show up.